# Why image always shows under buttons?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, layout

The ImageView is placed under the two buttons in xml file, but when the ImageView is moved programmatically to the buttons' position, the buttons cover the ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NewGameViewActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgColor" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_width="160px"
    android:layout_height="160px"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:layout_gravity="top|start"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/undo_button"
    android:layout_width="160px"
    android:layout_height="160px"
    android:text="UNDO"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tutorial_hand"
    android:layout_width="140px"
    android:layout_height="140px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/hand" />
```

Comment: How do you move it? add code please.

Comment: @mrzbn problem solved. Just use animator to change its position.